# Some kind of Dashboard in FullCalendar

Tags: events, fullcalendar, dashboard, duration, week-number

[yeah what more to describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrZVR.png)

I have no clue how to do that. Setup fullcalendar, fetsch data and enter data works fine.
The last thing I needit is a Dashboard under the Calendar witch get the selected week that visible in the Calendar (would be great when act also with the prev and next Arrow Buttons form the Calendar), and get the summary Events from selected Week witch holds already the durration of the single Events.

Do you know what a mean? and *shy asking* would you be ma hero?

Comment: `get the summary Events from selected Week witch holds already the durration of the single Events.`...this part I don't understand, sorry. What are "summary" events? Are they different from "single" events somehow? I think you need to provide some specific examples of what you mean and what you want.

Comment: Hi ADyson, thanks asking. I am trying to create a time record. Employees can use it to record the hours they have worked. It would now be practical if the logged in user could see his recorded time in the displayed calendar week. The total of the hours worked (see picture) / the hours to be fulfilled. Summary = Total = Sum(things + things = Sumary)  -> my Englisch is not very well ;-D

Comment: Here a link for more than a Picture - a little bit of Code: https://codepen.io/misik/pen/JjbeJev

Answer (score 1):

Maby i found the Solution

main.js
`weekNumberClassNames: function(view, element){ $('#card-title').html(calWeek); }`

Let the magic happen by every view change, it also the WeekNumber change
A big part is solved.